# How to extract Jester dataset files?

Tags: gzip, tar, zip, 7zip

I am trying to extract the dataset given on link:https://20bn.com/datasets/jester

I am unable to extract these file with no extension. I tried using tar and also what they have mentioned on their website, i.e.,

```
  cat 20bn-jester-v1-?? | tar zx
```

Please assist.

Comment: Could you please share the Jester data? Even part of that. I'm trying to apply the data, it seems like a long term and I cannot wait for long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read on the web site:

> The video data is provided as one **large TGZ archive**, split into parts of 1 GB max

so you need to combine the files and the extract.
the command like this can help you:

```
cat 20bn-jester-v1-??|gzip -dc|tar xf -
```

`cat` is used to combine all parts in one file, then `gzip` to decompress the file and on the end `tar` to extract the file(s)

Comment: do you know how to solve this problem for 7zip files? I am trying to the same thing with nvgesture dataset: https://research.nvidia.com/publication/online-detection-and-classification-dynamic-hand-gestures-recurrent-3d-convolutional

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced the same problem for quite some time but I figured out you can use ***GitBash*** to unzip the data. just open Gitbash inside the folder where you downloaded the data by right-clicking and selecting gitbash (you must have it installed). then type in the command **cat 20bn-jester-v1-?? | tar zx**. Press enter and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

First: `unzip '*.zip'` 
Then: `cat 20bn-jester-v1-?? | tar zx`